# Max number in array algorithm, when array's size is power of 2

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, max

I've found this algorithm and i have been asked what this algorithm does.

Given an array A with Integers, when the array size is power of 2. 
What does the algorithm returns?

```
1. k <- n
2. while k>1 do:
   2.1. k <- k/2
   2.2. for i <- 1 to k do:
      2.2.1. if A[i] < A[i+k]
           2.2.1.1 swap A[i] and A[i+k]
3. return A[1]
```

I'm almost sure this algorithm returns the largest number in the array.

My questions are:

1. How long the algorithm takes? I think O(n), but not sure.
2. How can I proof it returns the largest number?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe that your conclusions are correct. The proof is simply that the largest number will always be moved to the first half of the subarray (if it's not there already).

Answer (score 2):

*How long the algorithm takes? I think O(n), but not sure.*

`O(n)` is correct. Note that on each iteration you are reducing the size of the array to be checked by half, so there will be exactly `log(n)` steps, since `n` is a power of two.

So the final complexity is `n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... + 1`, these are exactly `log(n)` terms. This is a geometric sequence whose summation is `n-1`, which is `O(n)`.

*How can I proof it returns the largest number?*

In each iteration `i`, you have the largest element in the first `n/2^i` elements of the array, so after `log(n)` steps the first element of the array is the largest number of the array.

Comment: @ruakh Yes you are correct. I missed that. Fixed the answer.